# How to pass data from two different controller to single view in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel5. There are two controllers Dashboard.php and Stats.php. I want to pass variables from both controllers to my single view DashBoard.blade.php 
Guide me is this possible and also guide me the about the route of project.

here is my routing code:

` Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/DashBoard', 'DashBoard@ratingdata')->name('DashBoard');

Route::get('/Stats', 'Stats@statsdata')->name('Stats'); `

It works when views are different. but i need data on single view

Comment: Just return same view from both controller actions and pass data with same name. e.g. `return view('DashBoard', ['data' => $data]);`

Comment: Why do you want to pass data from two different controllers? I would suggest to create functions in the model and call them to fetch data because your view will load from single controller only.

Answer (score 1):

About the routes, you can use the resources routing, it will create all your basic routes. Check this out (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

**A example of that, would be:**

```
Route::resource('/dashboard', 'DashboardController');
Route::resource('/stats', 'StatsController');
```

To display data of multiple models in a view all you need to do is declare the model in the beggining of your controller.

**Example:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Stats;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $stats = Stats::all();
    $dashboard = Dashboard::all();

    return view('the_view_you_wanna_show', compact('stats', 'dashboard'));
}
```

Then, all you need to do now, is go to your view and display your data.

**Example:**

```
<h1>Displaying the names of my dashboard</h1>
@foreach($dashboard as $names)
 {{$names->name}}
@endforeach

<h1>Displaying the stats name</h1>
@foreach($stats as $stats_names)
 {{$stats_names->name}}
@endforeach
```

**Tip:**
When you create your models, go to your prompt and type:

```
php artisan make:model NameOfYourModel -a
```

It will create all the things you need to manipulate this model.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of get route to fetch user data and display in view -

**Route**

```
  Route::get('edit_profile', 'AdminController@editProfile');
```

**In AdminController**

```
public function  editProfile(){
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';
        $data['profile_info'] = Admin::where('id',1)->first();

        return view("Admin::layout.edit_profile", $data);
    }
```

You can print profile info in view as -

```
{{$profile_info->name}}
```